# I can't use javah -v XX to get the constant pool structure

Tags: java, class, jvm, bytecode, javah

I can't use `javah -v XX` to look the constant pool structure

the code:

```
public class Demo {
    private int m;

    public int plus() {
        return m + 1;
    }
}
```

execute `javac Demo.java` and generated the `Demo.class`

so, I type the command `javah -v Demo`, but an error has occurred:

```
Error: Could not find class file for 'Demo'.
```

I have tried `javah -v Demo.class`, but there is also an  error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: Demo.class
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:177)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:68)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:509)
at com.sun.tools.javah.JavahTask.run(JavahTask.java:335)
at com.sun.tools.javah.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

but I want somthing like:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOuWS.png)

this is My `javah` path :

```
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javah
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view class constant pool you need `javap` tool, not `javah`.

If `Demo.class` is in current directory, specify `.` as the class path:

```
javap -cp . -v Demo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct the path to your class with the real path and the package structure if required. For ex. if the Demo.class is in a package called demo, do this:

```
javah -v demo.Demo
```

Comment: and you have to have the right class path